# Выполнение скрипта по времени

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, javascript

Нужно, чтобы код начал выполняться в определенное время, например, в 19:00, как реализовать? На JS и JQuery.

Comment: @RomanAnanev, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто периодически проверять локальное время пользователя и при наступлении 19.00 выполнять нужную функцию.

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); // вернет время в формате час:минуты:секунды
```

Но пользователь может попросту закрыть окно браузера, скажем, в 18.59 и открыть заново в 19.01, и ничего не сработает. Так как JavaScript не работает, если окно закрыто, что логично.

Answer (score 0):

Если у пользователя открыт ваш сайт, то через setInterval, например, каждую секунду проверять время. Если закрыт, то через Cron.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var start_hour = 18;

function doSomething(){
 alert("Hello World!");
}

var _inter = setInterval(function(){
 // Если время не пришло - прерываемся
 if(new Date().getHours() < 18)return;
 
 // Прерываем таймер
 clearInterval(_inter);

 // Стартуеем!
 doSomething();
}, 300);// Проверяем трижды на секунду. Думаю, этого хватит
```